# How can i check that EC2 AMI image is stored on EBS not ephemeral stoarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, web, amazon-ec2

I have just launched the micro instance with `Centos AMI image`. I have heard that if i stop the instance then my chnages will be lost. So i have read that if i use `EBS` then chnages will be saved.

But Its not clear to me how to do that. I want that if i stop or restart the machine then my chnages are still there.

DO i need to chnage my hard drive to `EBS`. How can i do that

My Root Device is comming as `EBS` with 10GB EBS volume. Is that ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the micro instances always use EBS root, so you don't have to do anything special.

If you 'stop' your instance, and later start, it's moving your hard drive to another computer and rebooting.

If you terminate your instance, your EBS drive will be fine as long as "delete EBS drive on termination" is not set on your drive.

When you use other instances, you'll have to verify the AMI type. Not all AMIs are available in all combinations:

- EBS vs ephemeral
- 64 bit vs 32bit
- PVM vs HVM (Everything is PVM except the really high-end Compute Cluster)

When you first get started in the cloud, EBS is a big deal. But as you get to be a cloud expert, you'll prefer non-EBS instances. EBS will only be used on a few servers, like your database or your syslog server.  Most of your app should be stateless. Your app servers should only store their data in the database, and only write their logs to a central logging server, and only get their code from github or a package repository. So so there is no need to 'backup' your app server boxes, since they can be re-created at any time from external sources using something like Puppet or Chef.

Only your 'stateful' boxes like databases need backing up, and EBS helps there.

Comment: o man you are great, ur answer make perfect sense. can i use puppet, chef in EC2. ANy example tutorial because i want to follow best practices

Comment: Yes, you can use Puppet, Chef, Salt, Ansible, etc. You'll probably want to level up on Amazon API/EBS/EC2/AMIs before diving into those.